# Existence of four dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^3$ defined by $f=(e^{f_1},-e^{f_1},e^{f_3})$ where $f_1,f_3:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ are holomorphic. $\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}$

We identify $\mathbb{C}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^6$: ($z_1,z_2,z_3)=(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3$). Let $H_1$, $H_2$, $H_3$ and $H_4$ be four hyperplanes in $\mathbb{C}^3$, defined by;
 $$\begin{array}{ccc}
&H_1=&\Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(1,0,0,0,0,0);(0,1,0,0,0,0)\big],\\
&H_2=&\Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(0,0,1,0,0,0);(0,0,0,1,0,0)\big],\\
&H_3=& \Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(0,0,0,0,1,0);(0,0,0,0,0,1)\big],\\
&H_4=&\Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(1,0,1,0,1,0);(0,1,0,1,0,1)\big].\\
\end{array}$$
$\textbf{Question}$: Is there a real subspace, H, of real dimension four such that $\Span_{\mathbb{R}}(H_i,H_ j, H^\perp)= \mathbb{R}^6$ for all $i\neq j$, $~~~~i,j \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4\rbrace,$ and such that $f$ avoid H?

I tried the four dimensional subspace :

$$\textbf{(H)} \  \left\{\begin{array}{ccllll}
X_1-X_2&=&0 & \\
 X_1-X_3&=&0&\\
\end{array}\right.
$$

$f$ avoid this subspace, but $H^\perp=\Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(-1,0,-1,0,0,0);(-1,0,0,0,-1,0)\big]$ does not satisfies the condition $\Span_\mathbb{R}(H_i,H_j,H^\perp)=\mathbb{R}^6$ for all $j\neq k,~~j,k\in\lbrace 1,...,4\rbrace$\
I tried also the following four dimensional subspace:

$$H=\left\{\begin{array}{cllll}
2y_1+x_2+y_2+y_3&=&0\\
~~\\
 x_1+2x_2+2x_3+y_2&=&0 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Then $H^\perp=\Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(0,2,1,1,0,1);(1,0,2,1,2,0)\big]$, which of course satisfies the condition $\Span_\mathbb{R}(H^\perp,H_j,H_k)=\mathbb{R}^6$ for all $j\neq k,~~j,k\in\lbrace 1,...,4\rbrace$, but $f$ does not avoid This subspace. ask me please for more information.